# Header missing in mail reply

Tags: java, email, outlook, azure-ad-graph-api

I was trying to send mail with graphClient with custom headers and expecting same headers in reply mails also so that i can track my conversation but i didn't got same headers in reply is that any way to got same headers in all reply .

```
    Message message = new Message();
    message.subject = "9/9/2018: DRaft _ testing";
    ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
    body.content = "The group represents Nevada.";
    message.body = body;
    LinkedList<Recipient> toRecipientsList = new LinkedList<Recipient>();
    Recipient toRecipients = new Recipient();
    EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
    emailAddress.address = "dummy@ggg.net";
    toRecipients.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    toRecipientsList.add(toRecipients);
    message.toRecipients = toRecipientsList;

    SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty = new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty();
    singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty.id="propery-id_graph";
    singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty.value ="propery-id_graph/Aamir";
    List<SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty> singleValueLegacyExtendedProperties = new LinkedList<>();
    singleValueLegacyExtendedProperties.add(singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty);
    SingleValueLegacyExtendedPropertyCollectionRequestBuilder builder=new SingleValueLegacyExtendedPropertyCollectionRequestBuilder()
    message.singleValueExtendedProperties = new SingleValueLegacyExtendedPropertyCollectionPage(singleValueLegacyExtendedProperties);
    LinkedList<InternetMessageHeader> internetMessageHeadersList = new LinkedList<InternetMessageHeader>();
    InternetMessageHeader internetMessageHeaders = new InternetMessageHeader();
    internetMessageHeaders.name = "x-Header-1";
    internetMessageHeaders.value = "aaa";
    internetMessageHeadersList.add(internetMessageHeaders);
    InternetMessageHeader internetMessageHeaders1 = new InternetMessageHeader();
    internetMessageHeaders1.name = "x-Header-2";
    internetMessageHeaders1.value = "bbb";
    internetMessageHeadersList.add(internetMessageHeaders1);
    message.internetMessageHeaders = internetMessageHeadersList;
```

Answer (score 0):

No headers will be copied in replies. You cannot even expect the subject to be the same since the user can change it. Your best hope is that "in-Reply-To" header will be set to the message id of your original email.